# Weird index issue in Backbone click event callback

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have this code, it's independent and isolated. The problem I am having is that the index i is starting at 1 instead of starting at 0. I have no idea why this could be, and doesn't seem to have anything to do with the closure that I am pushing into the deletes array...but I can't be sure, no idea what the issue is.

```
    onClickResetAll: function (event) {
                    event.preventDefault();

                    var deletes = [];

                    Object.keys(collections).forEach(function (key) {
                        if (collections.hasOwnProperty(key)) {

                            var coll = collections[key];

                            for (var i = 0; i < coll.models.length; i++) {

                                deletes.push(function (callback) {

                                    var index = i; //i starts at 1, not 0 !!!
                                    coll.models[index].deleteModel(function (err, resp, x) {

                                        console.log(err, resp, x);

                                        if(err){
                                            callback(err);
                                        }
                                        else{
                                            callback(null,null);
                                        }

                                    });
                                });
                            }

                        }
                    });

                    async.parallel(deletes,function(err,results){

                        Backbone.Events.trigger('bootRouter',  '+refreshCurrentPage');

                    });

                }, //end of onClickResetAll callback function

//end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem isn't really that `i` starts at one, the problem is that `i` will be `coll.models.length` for every function in `deletes`. Why would that be? Well, each function is sharing the same `i` and `i` won't be evaluated until the functions inside `deletes` are actually called.

The solution is to force `i` to be evaluated when it has the value you want (i.e. evaluated `i` when you're building the callback function). There are various solutions and they're all variations on the "wrap it in a function to break the reference" theme:

1. Use an iterator with a callback function instead of a plain `for` loop:

   ```
   coll.each(function(model, i) {
       // `model` is the model from the collection, `i` is the loop index.
   });
   ```

   You can use `each` here because Backbone [collections have a bunch of Underscore functions built in](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-Underscore-Methods).
2. Wrap the loop body in an SIF:

   ```
   for(var i = 0; i < coll.models.length; ++i)
       (function(i) {
           //...
       })(i);
   ```
3. Use a separate function to build your functions:

   ```
   function make_deleter(coll, i) {
       return function(callback) {
           coll.models[i].deletedModel(function(err, resp, x) {
               //...
           }
        }
   }

   //...

   for(var i = 0; i < coll.models.length; ++i)
       deletes.push(make_deleter(coll, i));
   ```

They all do pretty much the same thing: add an extra function call into the mix to force `i` to be evaluated (rather than just referenced) on each iteration of the loop.

In a Backbone situation, **1** would probably be the most natural and you wouldn't even need your troublesome `i` with that approach.

Comment: ha! I was hoping the var index = i; call would circumvent this problem, but I guess not

Comment: That's not enough because `i` is still `i` when you `index = i` and that doesn't happen until the function is called. Also be aware that the model at a particular index will change as models are deleted so `coll.models[i]` won't always be the model you think it is.

Comment: ahh, the statement you just made explains exactly why my current methodology of deleting models was not deleting/destroying all of them, do you have a suggestion on how to delete all the models in a collection then, if iterating through them poses the problem you just described?

Comment: If you use `coll.each(function(model) { ... })` then you have `model` in hand so there's no need for manual indexing.

Comment: gotcha, thanks for the spoonfeeding :) it is appreciated

Comment: I added a new answer I meant the answer to be a comment, but now that it's a separate answer I will just leave it and update it. I appreciate your suggestions and at this point in time #1 is in place.

Answer (score 0):

another solution to this is using async.each or async.eachSeries instead of async.parallel. using the first 2 avoids pushing to an array of functions altogether.